# VB.net work out number of days between two dates

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to work out the number of days between two dates and whether it is a full month or not.

I currently have this code:

```
    Dim fromdate As Date
    Dim todate As Date
    Dim timespan
    Dim num_days As String
    Dim month As DateTime

    fromdate = Date.Parse("01/01/2017")
    todate = Date.Parse("31/01/2017")
    TimeSpan = todate - fromdate
    num_days = TimeSpan.Days

    MsgBox(num_days)
```

And then I try to work out if it is a full month:

```
month = todate
If (month.Month = "02" And num_days = "28") Or num_days = "29" Or num_days = "30" Or num_days = "31" Or num_days = "0" Then
    'do code here
Else
    'do code here
End If
```

But this is proving to not work in February because it only sees the `num_days` as 27

Is there a way I can get the correct number of days between the two dates including the dates themselves being full days?

And how can I check if it is a full, correct month or not

**UPDATE**

The purpose of this is for a billing system so files are read into a database with from and to dates then it needs to work out the pricing from those dates.

So a product has a specific price, but first of all we need to work out whether to bill for part of a month or a full month (basically part of the product price or the full price)

So these 'Full Month' date range examples will bill the full price

Full Month:

- 01/01/2017 - 31/01/2017
- 25/01/2017 - 25/01/2017
- 18/01/2017 - 18/02/2017
- 10/01/2017 - 10/01/2018

Whereas, this date range for 'Part Month' will only bill for the number of days between the from and to date (+1 day)

Part Month

- 15/01/2017 - 31/01/2017

Comment: Did you notice the 'RELATED' section on the right? There are a lot of similar questions (if not a direct duplicate) None of them is good for you?

Comment: no i dont see that section?

Comment: I checked a few other questions but cannot find any the same as mine. I want to be able to find not only the number of days BETWEEN the 2 dates, but also include the dates. for example, if its 01/01/2017 to 04/01/2017 i should return 4 and not 3

Comment: Alright, I deleted my answer for now

Comment: Another attempt..

Comment: The problem with this question is... what is a month... A month is really a vague concept in general... Perhaps back it up a bit an try and explain what your are trying to achieve.. (not the code... but the desired functionality.)

Comment: ok, take a look now

Comment: OK so can one guarantee that the month part of the date will ALWAYS be the "Next month".... Ie could it ever be like Jan 29th - Mar 2nd

Comment: correct, it will always either be the same month or just the next month

Comment: there is another that i have just added too - 10/01/2017 - 10/01/2018 - could be the same date but just the next year

Comment: how about this if statement: `If days_between+1 = num_of_days_in_month Or fromdate = todate Or (fromdate.Day = todate.Day And todate.Month = fromdate.Month+1) Or (fromdate.Day = todate.Day And fromdate.Month = todate.Month And todate.Year = fromdate.Year+1) Then 'Full Month Else 'Part Month End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would get what you specified:

```
Dim IsOneFullMonth = (d1.Day = 1 And d2 = d1.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1))
Dim IsOnMonthLater = (d2 = d1.AddMonths(1))
```

The two states are not really the same thing in my understanding.
The second check is one month and one day.
(The first would match 'Jan 01 - Jan 31', the second one 'Jan 01 - Feb 01'.)

Also consider that neither check would match 'end of months' like `2016-02-29` - `2016-03-31` - you have to really define what you want to achieve in those cases.

Comment: i was actually just trying this before you posted it :) that seems to be working, although ive run into something else. if the dates are 18/01/2017 - 18/02/2017 it is seeing that as 32 days and therefore thinks its part of a month and not a full month because 32 <> 31 (31 = days in the month)

Comment: I guess I need to do <= rather than =

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I added something

Comment: ok, see my update for what i mean by full and part month. sorry i should have explained a little more

Comment: i have just tried this and these dates are showing as part of a month: (18/01/2017 - 18/01/2017) but that should show as a Full Month and these are also showing as Part Month but they should be a full month: (18/01/2017 - 18/02/2017)

Comment: I have added this code `If fromdate.Day = 1 And todate = fromdate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1) Then 'full month Else 'Part Month End If`